# How delete virus /tmp/.git/kthreaddw from ubuntu server

Tags: malware, ubuntu-server

I have a ubuntu server which have some laravel project  , couple of weeks I found one site crashed due to malware. Please help me remove malware from ubuntu server?

[image: kthreadw]

Comment: This question is not about programming, but rather about server administration, and does not belong on the site. You may wan to ask on AskUbuntu. However, know that once your machine has been compromised, deleting files may not be enough to fix anything (malware often does whatever a remote controller tells it to, which often includes adding backdoors to reinfect a machine; gone are the days where you could reasonably expect to "remove a virus" by deleting a few files) - **a full reinstall is the only way to ensure integrity**.

Comment: I have the same issue running a GitLab server in my local ubuntu. See this thread https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345091 to find how to resolve it. There are a few ways, but I will recommend disabling the public registrations for now, until you find a good way to get rid of the malwere.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem today , it was a problem with the gitlab-ce version 13.*.